# How to create a custom list page with only draft posts in Hugo?

Tags: hugo

So, theme is in place, I can list all posts and access each one of them when Hugo server is running, being draft or not.

I'm trying to create a custom list but, after some research, I couldn't find how to list only draft posts.

Can you help me to create a custom Hugo page that list only draft posts when  it's config has `draft: true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the [newly released Hugo 0.65.0](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/tag/v0.65.0) (Feb. 2020) could help:

> The front matter fields that control when and if to publish a piece of content (`draft`, `publishDate`, `expiryDate`) now also works for list pages (like sections and the home page), and is recursive.

Comment: I'll give it a try later this or the next month :) Thanks!

Comment: @William No problem (since "next month" is in a few days ;)). Of course, that would be 0.65.3 now (https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases)

Comment: Downloading the latest Hugo Release (0.66.0) and navigating to `http://localhost:1313/draft/`, the `post-list.html` shows only draft posts now :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For some purposes it is useful just to have a catalog of the drafts in the content directory. A list of drafts is easy to obtain by issuing in the command line:

```
hugo list drafts
```